# Javascript/HTML assigning a value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a problem with some Javascript/HTML/CSS code. I am fairly new to creating websites, so please bear with me.

what I am ultimately trying to do is pull a dynamic value from javascript and use that to sort some divs (in a container). What I am thinking is I will assign the value to the Id and then pull those into an array to be sorted by tinysort. If there's a faster way to do this, let me know.

However, my first problem is putting the data into the id so it can be sorted. Would I do something like

```
document.getElementById(namesort).value = iterator;
```

or would I use something like `myData`?

Note: I don't want to display the value, I just want to use it to sort.

Please ask for clarification if needed! Thanks in advance. :)

Here is the applicable code to this problem. http://jsfiddle.net/dw77hLyp/1/

It just basically shows a very basic outline of some of my code.

Comment: Add complete code here

Comment: You mentioned "dynamic" but the way that it changes might be important (PHP, vs clicking a button). Remember you can just store a variable as `var myVar = ...etc...` and that will last between event listeners.

Comment: So, I mean dynamic in that the value can either be 1, 2, or 3 based on some time constraints. I need to figure out how to connect it with HTML divs so that I can reorganize them based on that status. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without JQuery. You can create your attribute :

```
 document.getElementById(namesort).createAttribute('myData');
     document.getElementById(namesort).setAttribute("myData","hello Im in");
```

Comment: So, with this code, each element would have a new attribute set to my value (which is a number value. Does it have to be a string?) which can all be compared to each other, right?

Comment: It should be a string, yes. // but no problem, you can easily convert string to int & vice-versa (see parseInt).

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS Solution:

```
for( i = 0 ; i < iterator.length ; i++ ) {
    document.getElementsByName('namesort')[i].setAttribute('data-sort',iterator[i]);
}
```

That way you add each of those elements an attribute called `data-sort` where the `iterator` as a value, then could create an array insert all the namesort elements to it, use the sorting algorithm and you're done.

Comment: So, I would add them individually into an array like var arrayName = [itemNames]? or would I insert them in another way?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML="someContent";
```